# How to fix "A heap has been corrupted" run-time error?

Tags: c, heap-memory

I'm trying to make a code that gets a pointer to an array of pointers. The pointers point to strings, but each one of them has 50 bytes of memory allocated to them, so I made this function to allocate the minimum amount of memory. But for some reason, realloc throws a runtime error (A heap has been corrupted). Any ideas for the source of the problem and how to fix it?

```
int reallocToMinSize(char** friends, int len)
{
    int i = 0;
    int reallocSuccess = 1;
    char* newFriendPtr = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < len && reallocSuccess; i++)
    {
        printf("Reallocating: %s, size: %i", friends[i], (strlen(friends[i]) + 1));
        friends[i] = (char*) realloc(friends[i], (strlen(friends[i]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (friends[i] == 0)
        {
            reallocSuccess = 0;
        }
        printf("%s\n", friends[i]);
    }
    return reallocSuccess;
}
```

Comment: Need more code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: is `printf("Reallocating: %s, size: %i", friends[i], (strlen(friends[i]) + 1));` always prints something valid ?

Comment: If re-allocation fails, and you assign the return value of realloc to friends[i], then you have a null pointer and you should not use it in printf.

Comment: I suspect your initial values of `friends[i]` are not compatible with a realloc (third case in my answer)

Comment: The notorious problem with this diagnostic is that it is triggered *after* code has corrupted the heap.  Could have happened an hour ago.  You don't find out until you allocate more with malloc/realloc, only then does the runtime need to walk the heap to find more space and discovers that its internal structure is compromised.  So the snippet cannot help us help you, you'll have to focus on the rest of your code to find the bug.

Comment: NVM I found out what the problem was;
when I used malloc on the pointer to the pointers' I multiplied by the size of char instead of by the size of a pointer to a char, which means that there was probably a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Probable causes are

- you never initialized `friends[i]` before to do the *realloc*
- or you *realloc* a freed block
- or `friends[i]` was not set by NULL or the result of *malloc*

Because you do

> ```
>  realloc(friends[i], (strlen(friends[i]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
> ```

and the *printf* just before is probably valid I suspect you are in third error case and you do something wrong like

```
friends[i] = "aze";
... 
reallocToMinSize(friends, ...);
```

or

```
char s[...];
... 
friends[i] = s;
... 
reallocToMinSize(friends, ...);
```

or

```
char * s = malloc(...);
... 
friends[i] = s + offset; /* offset not null */
... 
reallocToMinSize(friends, ...);
```

or

```
... 
friends[i] = strtok(...);
... 
reallocToMinSize(friends, ...);
```

or may be the second error case doing

```
char * s = malloc(...); /* unique allocation */
...
for (i = ...) { ... friends[i] = s; ... } /* always the same value of s */
... 
reallocToMinSize(friends, ...);
```

because *malloc* can free its first argument, so in *reallocToMinSize* for a given index you apply *realloc* on a block freed for a lower index

Comment: friends[i] indeed isn't NULL, it is already populated with strings, but their allocated size is 50, and I want to reduce it to the minimum size(AKA the size of the string +1), isn't that a thing that realloc can do? reallocate the size of a string to a smaller / longer size, while keeping its data?